# Android - Attempt to invoke method '...' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting the error 'Attempt to invoke method '...' on a null object reference' on Android when trying to access a field which was set previously.
I check upon setting it that it's not null, but when it's accessed in a different activity, it 'null'.
This field is created along with multiple others' and for some reason, it's the only one which appear to old a null reference.

**Object in question**

```
public enum Locations {
    Meeting_Room,Office_245,Lobby,NOC,VPsoffice
}
```

**Class declaration:**

```
public class Task implements Serializable {

    private long taskId;
    private String description;
    private Boolean completed = false;
    private Category task_catg;
    private Task_Status task_sts;
    private Locations tsk_location;
}

public Locations getTsk_location() {
    return tsk_location;
}

public void setTsk_location(Locations tsk_location) {
    this.tsk_location = tsk_location;
}
```

Please note that **Task_Status** & **Category** are also enums, and I do not encounter any issues with them.

This is where the object is initialized, I've added prints here and saw that the value returned from the activity is not null.
**New Task activity**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_SELECT_LOCATION:
            {
                /*returned_selc_loc = (Locations) data.getSerializableExtra("location");
                loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                loc.setClickable(false);*/
                switch(Globals.temp)
                {
                    case 0:
                        returned_selc_loc=Locations.Meeting_Room;
                        loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                        loc.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        returned_selc_loc=Locations.Office_245;
                        loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                        loc.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        returned_selc_loc=Locations.Lobby;
                        loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                        loc.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        returned_selc_loc=Locations.NOC;
                        loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                        loc.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        returned_selc_loc=Locations.VPsoffice;
                        loc.setText(returned_selc_loc.toString());
                        loc.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the Task object is created and the Location is set:
**New Task activity**

```
    public void addTaskBtn (View view)
{
    boolean state=true;

    EditText desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newTaskDesc);
    EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taskDateEdit);
    EditText time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taskTimeEdit);
    loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taskLocation);

    Date myDate = null;
    RadioButton rb;
    String emp_name;

    t = new Task(desc.getText().toString());

    t.setTask_sts(Task_Status.WAITING);
    int position = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            t.setTask_catg(Category.GENERAL);
            break;
        case 1:
            t.setTask_catg(Category.CLEANING);
            break;
        case 2:
            t.setTask_catg(Category.ELECTRICITY);
            break;
        case 3:
            t.setTask_catg(Category.COMPUTERS);
            break;
        case 4:
            t.setTask_catg(Category.OTHER);
            break;
    }
    //Added prints here and value is set correctly, definitely not NULL.
    t.setTsk_location(returned_selc_loc);

    t.setTaskId(task_id);
    task_id++;
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    dbm = DBManager.getInstance(this);
    long seq_tsk_id = dbm.addTask(t);
    t.setTaskId(seq_tsk_id);

    returnIntent.putExtra("task", t);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish(); 
}
```

This is the call to the **Edit Task activity**, the call is from the MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    dbM = DBManager.getInstance(context);

    itemList = dbM.getAllTasks();
    list.setAdapter(new TaskItemAdapter(context, itemList));

    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {

            //get item instance from list
            Task tt = (Task) ((TaskItemAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

            if(true)
            {
                //start the create activity again, now for editing
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditTaskActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("task", tt);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TASK);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

**Edit Task activity**
This is I get the error (left only relevant part, as other variables in the object are successfully,

```
public void deleteTaskBtn(View view)
{
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    tastToEdit = (Task)i.getSerializableExtra("task");
    tastToEdit.setToDelete(true);

    ParseObject parse_task = new ParseObject("Task");
    parse_task.put("Description",tastToEdit.getDescription());
    parse_task.put("DueDate",tastToEdit.getDueDate());
    parse_task.put("Priority",tastToEdit.getPriority().ordinal());
    int com_state = (tastToEdit.getCompleted()) ? 1 : 0;
    parse_task.put("IsCompleted",com_state);
    parse_task.put("Location", tastToEdit.getTsk_location().ordinal());

    parse_task.put("Category",tastToEdit.getTask_catg().ordinal());
    parse_task.put("Status", tastToEdit.getTask_sts().ordinal());
    parse_task.put("TeamName",Globals.team_name);
    parse_task.put("Employee",tastToEdit.getEmp_name());

    parse_task.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("msg","deleted");
            } else {
                Log.d("msg", "not deleted");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });

    returnIntent.putExtra("task",tastToEdit);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

This line returns that NULL reference:

```
Location selected_loc = tastToEdit.getTsk_location();
```

**Full error stack**

```
03-09 21:28:20.192 10425-10425/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-09 21:28:20.229 10425-10433/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-09 21:28:20.240 10425-10425/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2-1/lib/arm
03-09 21:28:20.446 10425-10456/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-09 21:28:20.508 10425-10456/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
03-09 21:28:20.511 10425-10456/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-09 21:28:27.832 10425-10425/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-09 21:28:28.397 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb38ccf80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaef7fe30
03-09 21:28:29.620 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb39ba400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaef7f9e0
03-09 21:28:30.360 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb397f900 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb3b29370
03-09 21:28:32.921 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9f2cbb80 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0xb3b29530
03-09 21:28:33.437 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9f2cad80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb3b295d0
03-09 21:28:40.866 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 V/RenderScript: 0x9dca9000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
03-09 21:28:40.907 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3947700 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb3b29910
03-09 21:28:44.971 10425-10425/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/sdas: null
03-09 21:28:45.143 10425-10456/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb39b5380 (ListView) with handle 0xaef7f510
03-09 21:28:48.110 10425-10425/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-09 21:28:48.111 10425-10425/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2, PID: 10425
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.Location.ordinal()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.EditTaskActivity.deleteTaskBtn(EditTaskActivity.java:372)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But as you can see, this field is set successfully previously, in another activity.

What can be the cause?

Comment: David, you've said the error occurs in the onCreate, but the stack trace given points to your deleteTaskBtn method in EditTaskActivity: `at il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.EditTaskActivity.deleteTaskBtn(EditTaskActivity.java:372)` where you seem to be calling ordinal() on a null Location object

Comment: Yes, it occurs on call of 'Location selected_loc = tastToEdit.getTsk_location();'
I resolved the issue in 'onCreate' by placing a default value.
If I remove the default value the error will occurs there as well.
Added the code from 'deleteTaskBtn'.

Comment: Hi I'm currently facing the same problem but I dont know how to add the check to place default value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that it's not about whether or not the field has been set, but rather the object you are trying to pull off the intent isn't there on this line in the `onCreate`:

```
tastToEdit = (Task)i.getSerializableExtra("task");
```

Add a check after this to see whether tastToEdit is null, and if so investigate why it hasn't been properly added to the intent if this is the case.

Comment: tastToEdit is not null, only the LOCATION is null.
Other fields in the 'tastToEdit' object exist.

Comment: @DavidFaiz If the tastToEdit is definitely not null, then can you post the full class definition of `Task`, more specifically the `getTsk_location` method and anything it relies on? Also, the full stack trace of the error you are getting would be great...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mistaken about what happens to the intent that you populated in one Activity's [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)).  That method is responsible for handling the result of the next activity which was invoked with [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).  That next activity can set a result for the prior activity using setResult(), which becomes available in onActivityResult() when the invoked activity finish.

However it looks like you're expecting getIntent() in "a different activity" to be able to see that Intent you created in onActivityResult().  That's simply not the case.  getIntent() returns the activity that was used to start the current activity that you're working with.  It's completely unrelated the intent from an activity result.  So you'll need to change your strategy for passing data around between these activities.

Comment: I haven't placed the code that calls the activity where I get the NULL issue.
Please note that 'tastToEdit' object is not null, only the LOCATION is null. Other fields in the 'tastToEdit' object exist.

Comment: In that case, where is the code that starts the "different activity" that contains the intent with the task that you expect the location to be non-null?  We need to be able to trace the path of all these objects.